# PM2 (Node.js) deploy - Host key verification failed

Tags: node.js, deployment, ssh, ssh-keys, pm2

When i trying make deploy, i have error

> Host key verification failed.
>   fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
>   error: Could not fetch origin
>
> fetch failed
>
> Deploy failed

My repo located on Bitbucket.
All ssh-keygen is added to Bitbucket

Any ideas?

Thank

Answer (score 0):

```
production: {
        user: 'ubuntu',
        key: '~/.ssh/node_ec2.pem',
        host: 'ec2-52-221-188-28.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com',
        ref: 'origin/master',
        repo: 'git@gitlab.com:telkomdev/belajarcoding-apis.git',
        path: '/home/ubuntu',
        'post-deploy': 'npm install && pm2 startOrRestart 
ecosystem.config.js'
}
```

You must give ssh on your user when connecting, for example above is ubuntu user, not root user on **ecosystem.config.js**.